# Methods in same Component - auto updating

Tags: node.js, vue.js

So I know how to do this in the HTML itself. But I would rather not have to hide this using a div tag and class. So here is what I have:

```
<template>
 <div id="navJade" class="inactive">
    <h1>Jade Skill Calculations</h1>
    <span>Jack of all Jade:</span><input type="number" min="0" max="50" v-model='joaj'></span>Max: 50<br/>
    {{joaj = joajCalc(joaj)}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Jade',


  data() {
    return {
      joaj: 0
    }
  },

  methods: {
    joajCalc: (a) => {
      if (a >= 51) a = 50;
      return a;
    }
  }


}
</script>
```

So, while this `{{joaj = joajCalc(joaj)}}` in the template tag does what I want, in order for it not to be seen I'd have to hide it with an inactive class. I even tried using the method inside the `data()`, however, it only does it once and doesn't update as wanted. Of course I can use the way of hiding it, but I'd rather not, if I can avoid it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you may find that useful:

> computed properties are cached based on their dependencies. A computed
> property will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have
> changed.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

try this:

```
<template>
 <div id="navJade" class="inactive">
    <h1>Jade Skill Calculations</h1>
    <span>Jack of all Jade:</span><input type="number" min="0" max="50" v-model='joaj'></span>Max: 50<br/>
    {{joajCalc}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Jade',


  data() {
    return {
      joaj: 0
    }
  },
    computed:{
         joajCalc:function(){
      if (this.joaj >= 51) this.joaj = 50;
      return this.joaj;
    }
  }


}
</script>
```

Comment: >.> I read through this and missed my opportunity. I feel a bit dumb. Not sure why it didn't click in my mind to do this after I read the basic concepts page of vue. Gah, anyways, thank you very much!

Comment: Hmmm, this actually doesn't work, returns undefined.

Comment: sorry, i got that. seems to be that computed properties aint doing well with es6 arrow syntax. try this: `computed:{
         joajCalc:function() {
      if (this.joaj >= 51) this.joaj = 50;
      return this.joaj;
    }
  }` or check out my edit to the answer. thanks for the noting.

Comment: It's not just computed, even methods were return undefined like that, I guess the ES6 stuff the framework doesn't like. I'll keep in mind, thanks!